# array distributing contents to new array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to distribute the contents of this array into a new array, that the new array keys must contain only a total of **4 counts**, wherein `hit = 0` is equal to **1 count**, `hit = 1` is equal to **2 counts**.

Raw array fetch from database assigned to variable `$ret`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 33, [hits] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 32, [hits] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 31, [hits] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [id] => 30, [hits] => 0
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [id] => 29, [hits] => 0
        )
    [5] => Array (
            [id] => 28, [hits] => 1
        )
    [6] => Array (
            [id] => 27, [hits] => 0
        )
    [7] => Array (
            [id] => 26, [hits] => 0
        )
    [8] => Array (
            [id] => 25, [hits] => 1
        )
    [9] => Array (
            [id] => 24, [hits] => 0
        )
    [10] => Array (
            [id] => 23, [hits] => 1
        )
    [11] => Array (
            [id] => 22, [hits] => 1
        )
    [12] => Array (
            [id] => 21, [hits] => 0
        )
    [13] => Array (
            [id] => 20, [hits] => 1
        )
    [14] => Array (
            [id] => 19, [hits] => 1
        )
    [15] => Array (
            [id] => 18, [hits] => 0
        )
    [16] => Array (
            [id] => 17, [hits] => 0
        )
    [17] => Array (
            [id] => 16, [hits] => 0
        )
    [18] => Array (
            [id] => 15, [hits] => 0
        )
    [19] => Array (
            [id] => 14, [hits] => 1
        )
    [20] => Array (
            [id] => 10, [hits] => 0
        )
    [21] => Array (
            [id] => 9, [hits] => 1
        )
    [22] => Array (
            [id] => 8, [hits] => 0
        )
    [23] => Array (
            [id] => 7, [hits] => 0
        )
    [24] => Array (
            [id] => 3, [hits] => 1
        )
)
```

I constructed this code:

```
$new_arr = array();
$row = 0;
$ctr = 0;
foreach($ret as $ak1 => $av1) {
  if($ctr == 4) {
    $row++;
    $ctr = 0;
  }
  else {

  }
  if($av1['hits'] == 0) {
    $ctr++;
    $new_arr[$row][] = $av1;
  }
  else {
    $ctr+=2;
     $new_arr[$row][] = $av1;
  }
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

The first few keys `[0] [1] [2] [3]` seems to contains the proper result, but not with starting at key `[4]`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 33
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 32
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [id] => 31
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [3] => Array (
                    [id] => 30
                    [hits] => 0
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 29
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 28
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [id] => 27
                    [hits] => 0
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 26
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 25
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [id] => 24
                    [hits] => 0
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 23
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 22
                    [hits] => 1
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 21
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 20
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [id] => 19
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [3] => Array (
                    [id] => 18
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [4] => Array (
                    [id] => 17
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [5] => Array (
                    [id] => 16
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [6] => Array (
                    [id] => 15
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [7] => Array (
                    [id] => 14
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [8] => Array (
                    [id] => 10
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [9] => Array (
                    [id] => 9
                    [hits] => 1
                )
            [10] => Array (
                    [id] => 8
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [11] => Array (
                    [id] => 7
                    [hits] => 0
                )
            [12] => Array (
                    [id] => 3
                    [hits] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

I am so confused.

Comment: what happens when you're at 3, and then you add 2? you get 5, and `if($ctr == 4) {` will always be false. Maybe you should do all the 2's first, then all the 1's. btw- learn to debug. echo the values of your variables as the code runs so that you can see whats going on.

Comment: Probably, now I'm lost, I'm no expert in manipulating or shifting inside of array.

Comment: you either need to allow for groups of different sizes, or allow changing the order. Otherwise, your task sounds pretty impossible.

Comment: Speaking of order, how can at least achieve that?

Comment: My bad, what I mean is that you suggested changing the order. Can you please give me at least an insight how can I achieve that?

Comment: duplicate your foreach loop, but in the first one, skip all the 1's. in the second, skip all the 2's.

Comment: Do you need the sets to be optimally filled?  It's clear that id 19 should go to a new set in the result array, [5], because it would overflow set [4] to a "count" of 5.  When you reach id 18 do you want it to top off set [4] or just keep filling set [5] and leave set [4] with a "count" of 3?

Comment: I'm afraid that is the case. But the condition is every set must be total of 4. I'm aware of the overflow, that's why I am wondering how can I move the order of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you need to be able to track the "count" in each unfinished set.  This does the trick.  More details are in the code comments.

If you have any questions, ask in the comments and I'll edit this post as needed!

**Note**: This assumes hits will always be 0 or 1 (count 1 or 2).  It will need to be modified to work if items will ever have hits > 1 (count > 2).

**Edit**: Updated the code and results to take care of the issue brought up by @fishcracker.

```php
$sets = array();
// Because it's possible to have more than one unfinished set
$not_full = array();
// Because we need to track each set's count until it's full
$set_template = array("count" => 0);
$set = $set_template;
$max = 4;
foreach($ret as $item) {
    $item_count = $item["hits"] + 1;

    // If we have a 1 count and there are sets to be topped off
    if($item_count == 1 && !empty($not_full)) {
        $top_off = array_shift($not_full);
        $top_off[] = $item;
        unset($top_off["count"]);
        $sets[] = $top_off;
        continue;
    }

    // If we're going to overflow, push this set to potentially be topped off later
    if($set["count"] + $item_count > $max) {
        $not_full[] = $set;
        $set = $set_template;
    }

    // Add the item to the current set
    $set[] = $item;
    $set["count"] += $item_count;

    // This set is full, 
    if($set["count"] == $max) {
        unset($set["count"]);
        $sets[] = $set;
        $set = $set_template;
    }
}

// If we left the loop with an unfinished set which we were actively working on
if(count($set > 1)) {
    unset($set["count"]);
    $sets[] = $set;
}

// Append any unfinished sets that were waiting to be full
foreach($not_full as $set) {
    unset($set["count"]);
    $sets[] = $set;
}

print_r($sets);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 32
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 31
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 30
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 29
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 28
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 27
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 26
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 25
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 24
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [hits] => 1
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [hits] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
                [hits] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [hits] => 0
            )

    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [hits] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Superb! Let me study this, yet upon initial glance this is correct!

Comment: Great.  I tried to explain everything that's happening through the code comments, but let me know if you have any questions about it because if you don't understand how it works, I didn't do my job ;)

Comment: Question though, if say for example `$ret` only has two keys. It won't be added on the array sets, it needs at least 4.

Comment: Good catch!  I'll update the answer tomorrow if you or someone else doesn't get to it first.  All that needs to be done is, after the loop, and before appending leftovers, check to see if count($set) > 1 and if it is unset the ["count"] key and append it to $sets

Comment: Is it possible that in case a hits is considered leftover it is inserted in the next set rather than be populated at the bottom or last?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are matching `$ctr` against the number 4, which only works if the `$ctr` is exactly equal to 4 at the point of comparison. Since `$ctr` might increase by more than 1 each loop, it might surpass the 4.

Try:

```
if ($ctr >= 4)
```

instead.

Comment: Yeah you're right, however if I did that I might exceed the total of 4 counts. Some will result in 5 counts.

Comment: You need to be checking AFTER you add each value to the new array then

Comment: In that case it should reset $ctr and increase the row counter by one before it wants to increase $ctr by 2 if (and only if) $ctr == 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean but not 100%, is this what you're going for?

```
foreach($ret as $ak1 => $av1) {
    if($ctr >= 4){
         $row += 1;
         $ctr = 0;
    }
    if($ret[$ak1]['hits']){
        $ctr += 2;
    }
    else{
        $ctr += 1;
    }
    $new_arr[$row][$ret[$ak1]['id']] = $ret[$ak1]['hits'];
}
```

Works for me

Comment: Thanks for this, this is almost near the correct. However if you'll noticed key `[4]` has a total of 5 counts. Is there a way we can move this then get the next value that will fit so that it will total to just 4 counts?